# block yahoo messsenger

Tags: linux, firewall, proxy, iptables, squid

blocking yahoo messenger based on 
The order in which Yahoo Messenger scans for available ports is:

```
   1. port 5050
   2. port 80
   3. All available ports
```

is impossible,"its better disconnect internet :)"

the other way is to block yahoo messenger service addresses, like:

```
scs.msg.yahoo.com
scsa.msg.yahoo.com
scsb.msg.yahoo.com
scsc.msg.yahoo.com
```

and or these ip's like this:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 63.216.136.22 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.135.224.142    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.136.175.132    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.163.168.105    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.163.172.117    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.163.173.76 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.163.173.77 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.163.173.78 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.163.173.203    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.163.175.128    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 66.163.178.78 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 204.71.200.36 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 204.71.200.37 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 204.71.201.134    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 204.71.201.141    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.173.172   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.173.179   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.175.132   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.175.142   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.175.143   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.175.144   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.175.145   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.175.145   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.175.226   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.224.134   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.224.142   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.224.213   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.224.213   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.224.214   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.225.12    -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.226.117   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.226.118   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.226.209   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.226.210   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.227.168   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.233.129   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.233.130   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.233.131   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.233.133   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.233.135   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.233.148   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.233.151   -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTGOING -d 216.136.233.152   -j DROP
```

but, in new version of yahoo messenger i can connect.

is any other way to block yahoo messenger? or is fault in my above solutions?

Comment: You could also stop the installer from being downloaded/installed, then you don't need to worry about it being used :)

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP -d 0/0 --dport 5050 -j REJECT
```

This will reject requests on port 5050 going to any ip, please try it and let me know if it works for you

From what i read yahoo can use the http port aswell and i belive a fine way to catch it on the http would be having squid working on it.

You could block these aswell.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP --dport 5000:5100 -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP -d scsa.yahoo.com -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP -d cs.yahoo.com -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP -d scsa.msg.yahoo.com -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP -d messenger.yahoo.com -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP -d scs.msg.yahoo.com -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP -d scsb.msg.yahoo.com -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP -d scsc.msg.yahoo.com -j REJECT
```

**If yahoo messenger then tries to adapt itself picking up any other port you would need to start your firewall having a DROP ALL rule and then openning what you actually need, For example:**

Let's say your network is 192.168.1.0/24, the bellow rule will block it:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP -p tcp -i eth0
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP -p udp -i eth0
```

From here you would create what you want to permit, for example:

```
#allow only http traffic
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80
#allow only https traffic
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 443
```

Then if you have squid acting for http, https requests, etc. You would redirect it to squid, from squid you would filter http/s and any other related application from accessing the internet from that network.

You could aswell use squid with squidguard.

Comment: ok, i should test it.

Answer (score 0):

why not just give those hostnames a bogus IP (either via CNAME or A) in DNS rather than dropping the packets.  seems like it would be less of a load on your firewall (and fewer rules).

Comment: i say it's not working. you thinking of firewall performance !!!!

Comment: giving those particular hostnames non-routable IPs would solve your problem and reduce load on your systems.